# SAML settings: what is the issuer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saml

I've just started working with SAML (Ruby on Rails) and am trying to make a simple demo work. I'm using [this IdP](https://github.com/lawrencepit/ruby-saml-idp) and using OneLogin's ruby-saml. I'm currently stuck as to what the "issuer" is in the SAML settings that we are supposed to pass to `Authrequest.create`. I tried giving the `settings.issuer` something like `#{host_base_url}/:id` (where `host_base_url` is my SP's main page) but I get an error saying `Response Invalid.` with the explanation being that the issuer `is not a valid audience for this Response`. If I pass in an empty string, everything works though. I looked at the source code and it seems to have something to do with [the audiences](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/master/lib/onelogin/ruby-saml/response.rb#L456-L458) of which I also do not understand.

Does anyone know how I should properly set the issuer (i.e., what the issuer is supposed to be when I send an auth request to the IdP) such that my SP gets a proper response?

(I'm working on a Mac with OS X El Capitan, ruby 2.1 and rails 4.1 if that makes a difference.)

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you are using the optional `AudienceRestriction` condition which is not validating against whatever you are using as an issuer.  Can you add more details about implementation/configuration of your idP?  I guess the simple (and likely not very useful) answer is that your `issuer` should match data in your `Audience` node inside your `AudienceRestriction` condition.

Comment: This PDF can better explain the role and purpose of conditions and and AudienceRestriciton in particular (page 23):  https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf

Comment: Actually, the solution was in the code of the IdP that I was using. I had to add the issuer as a valid audience. Thanks for your reply though!